# Почему в этом предложении тире, а не двоеточие?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис

Почему в этом предложении тире, а не двоеточие? Ведь можно задать вопрос «а именно?» после слова обстоятельство.

Работа Фейнмана должна была бы вызвать восторг физиков во всех университетах, но возникло одно омрачающее радость обстоятельство - к решению этой проблемы, но совершенно иными путями пришли два учёных: Джулиус Швингер из Гарвардского университета и Синьитиро Томонага из Токийского университета.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сейчас говорят о вариативности знаков препинания — параллельном употреблении двоеточия и тире.
Розенталь говорит:

-В бессоюзном сложном предложении с изъяснительными отношениями встречается наряду с двоеточием также тире.

Ср.:
Я понял: важно, кто рисует (Гран.); Я понял — случилось горе, и молча хотел помочь (Ес.);

Ефрему казалось: не будет конца пути (Сарт.); И казалось — вот-вот немного, и Фёдор поймёт (Тендр.);

И судьи решили: если будет дождь, соревнования отменят; Заметил первый камень, решил — здесь клад, стал ковыряться (Тендр.).

Ср. постановку тире (вместо ожидаемого двоеточия) в предложениях этого типа: Он искоса посмотрел на неё — она очень молода и красива (М. Г.); Она оглянулась — на неё летела Васька в солдатской гимнастёрке, с угольно-чёрными бровями от переносья до висков (Пан.); Он выглянул из комнаты — ни одного огонька в окнах (Пан.); Посмотрел на прорубь — вода дремала (Шишк.).
Иногда в этих случаях вместо двоеточия употребляются запятая и тире как единый знак препинания: Я заглянул в гнёздышко, — там всего два птенчика(Вер.); Я обернулся, — всадник уже рядом (С об.); Поднял глаза, — стул подле стола был пустой (Сер.).

-Вариативны двоеточие и тире в бессоюзных сложных предложениях с пояснительными отношениями: Авторов этих писем волновали разные проблемы, но объединяло одно (: —) все они ждали от газеты конкретной и действенной помощи; Всех интересовал только один вопрос (: —) как поскорее выпутаться из создавшегося положения; Я помню пушок на его щеках (: —) он только начал бриться; На голове её цветной платок (: —) по алому полю зелёные розы; У меня правило (: —) никакого кофепития перед сном.

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=189

Answer (score 1):

> Работа Фейнмана должна была бы вызвать восторг физиков во всех
>   университетах, но возникло одно омрачающее радость обстоятельство  **—** к
>   решению этой проблемы, но совершенно иными путями пришли два учёных...
>
> Почему в этом предложении тире, а не двоеточие?

Потому что двоеточие было использовано чуть дальше:

> ...пришли два учёных: Джулиус Швингер из Гарвардского университета и
>   Синьитиро Томонага из Токийского университета.

А два двоеточия в одном предложении затруднили бы понимание текста.